# How many docker image we push to one private repository?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have a list of images which i want to push to the docker hub repository.
Here is my list of images,

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                     TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
testimage1                           latest              60927e450c80        6 days ago          596MB
testimage2                          latest              516082cd94fa        2 weeks ago         547MB
testimage3                           latest              5195076672a7        2 weeks ago         371MB
```

We can create only one private repository. So, is it possible push all the images to one private repository?
Please help me i have googled but didn't get any solution.

Comment: Will it be possible? Probably, but your question is so vague, it's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: @spender I have edited question for making it more clear.now you can able to understand it properly.

Comment: We push lots of images to our private repository. It's just a function of how much storage you have/want to use. There's probably vendor specifics that might be relevant, but you haven't indicated where your CR lives.

Comment: @spender so as per your suggestion i can push images one by one to my private repository?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After lots of trying, I found that We can only push one image to a private repository as a free user.If we push with the same tag then it will overwrite a repository image.And if we push with the different tag than it will push the repository as a public.

Comment: This is confirmed on the Docker documentation: _"you must name your local image using your Docker Hub username, and the repository name that you created through Docker Hub on the web."_ so that means one image = one repo

Answer (score 0):

When you build the images, you need to tag them with the registry url to be able to push them.

Instead of doing:

```
docker build -t testimage1 .
```

You should be doing:

```
docker build -t registry_host:port/testimage1
```

Then , you can push `registry_host:port/testimage1`.

Comment: I want to push all the images testimage1,testimage2,testimage3 to one repo registry_host:port/testimages.Now you will better understand

Comment: Your question is still not clear.
What registry do you use ?
Is `testimages` a namespace within a registry, or an image ?

Comment: If `testimages` is an image, than you can, as a hack, push different images by changing the tag.

Comment: I have one repo vimal ok i want to push multiple images like as I given in an example testimage1 then testimage2 and testimage3 to one private repository in my case vimal which i have created on docker hub.

Comment: then push your images like this:
`docker build -t vimal/testimage1:latest  ; docker push vimal/testimage1:latest` and repeat the same for other images.

Comment: I have tried to push image but on the private repository only one image uploaded if I try to push another image then it will make it as public.

Comment: so you can hack around with tags !

Comment: I have changed the tag but it will make image publically.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way of pushing multiple heterogeneous docker images. The trick would be to use a different tag for different images.
For example, Let the the docker repository be named **testimages**

We can have the following images at the same time:

**testimages:testimage1**

**testimages:testimage2**

and so on